# Phonegap + AngularJS geolocation doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to access the geolocation of phonegap inside a click event inside an angular controller, however, nothing seems to work(I only get console logged "clicked", nothing else), is there something special I have to do?
Code:

```
$("element").click(function(){  
    console.log('Clicked');
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        console.log('success');
    };

    function onError(error) {
        console.log('fail');
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    return false;
});
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you insert all required permissions into your config-file? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

Comment: Yes, I had it working in this exact same way before I added angular into the equation.

Comment: Then you could add some options like timeout this is important for getting current locations at bad positions. and setting maxmimumAge high enough is also recommended just like setting enableHighAccuracy on true.